# На каком объекте правильнее будет обработать нажатие клавиши?

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, dom, клавиатура

В задаче нужно было сделать смену некоего пространства (части формы) при нажатии "2", "3".
Поставил обработчик на html,body, но не ожидал, что будет реагировать и на инпуты, соответственно человек, пытаясь ввести номер телефона перескакивает на следующий пункт части формы. Какое исключение писать надо, если да, то как оно выглядеть должно или надо было вешать на что-то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ($(e.target).is('input')) {return;}
```

Пример

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/csLm2/

HTML

```
<div id="out">1</div>
<input type="text">
```

JavaScript

```
$('body').on('keydown',function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input')) return;
    $('#out').text(Math.random());
})
```